# Can't delete amplify app from amplify dashboard

Tags: aws-amplify

I Can't delete app_name app from the dashboard

Can't delete app_name app: Removing backend envs for app XXX failed

I deleted an associated S3 bucket & CloudFormation manually.

I've tried everything and I can't delete an app

Comment: did you create the amplify panel or CLI? If you created it in CLI, you must remove it from CLI.

Comment: AWS-Amplify's GitHub forum is having the same question. 
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/882

Answer (score 18):

open AWS CloudShell and  run cmd: `aws amplify delete-app --app-id <your_app-id>`

you can find amplify app id at amplify app detail

Comment: If you spend more than 10s looking for the app id... just click on the app in the overview and look at the last segment of your URL, that's the app id

Comment: yub, good idea, thank you.

Comment: Note that the `app-id` is separate from the app name, see this post for finding the `app-id` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67885683/how-to-find-the-aws-amplify-appid

Answer (score 1):

Try to use AWS CLI and either :

- run command "aws amplify delete-app" (you will need appid) or
- run command "aws amplify delete-backend-environment (you will need appid and environment name) and after that try to delete the app by using console again.

Comment: I had to disconnect a lot before this command worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you've been having an issue distinct from, but related to this one: [AWS Amplify: How to delete the environment, when resources are already partially deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55158153/aws-amplify-how-to-delete-the-environment-when-resources-are-already-partially)

In your case, you mention that you've deleted the S3 bucket & CloudFormation stack associated with the amplify app manually.

As of 9/26/2022 Amplify released an update that fixes issues deleting apps/backends, including issues where the s3 bucket and cloudformation stack was already deleted as you mention you have done.